# Кнопка и список css3:

Tags: css3

```css
.header_text img {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 750px;
}

.brig {
 color: #fff;
 font-family: Arial;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 32px;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 350px;
}

.nibiru {
 font-size: 28px;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 100px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: Arial;
 letter-spacing: 10px;
 position: relative;
}

.header_back button{
 width: 160px;
 margin-top: 680px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: block;
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 14px;
 position: relative;
 background: #01C699;
 border: 1px solid #01C699;
 padding: 12px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.header_menu {
 position: relative;
 color: #fff;
 padding-left: 10px;
display: inline-block;
}

ul .header_menu {
 
}

ul .header_menu li {
 

}
```

```html
 <header>
  <div class="header_back">
   <div class="header_text">
    <img src="images/thumb-1920-75604.jpg" alt="">
   </div>
   <p class="nibiru">nibiru</p>
   <div class="brig">Bringing you closer to pixel perfection</div>
   <button>Learn more</button>
  </div>
  <ul class="header_menu">
   <li>home</li>
   <li>portfolio</li>
   <li>team</li>
   <li>pages</li>
   <li>shortcodes</li>
   <li>about</li>
   <li>contact</li>
   <li>blog</li>
  </ul>
 </header>
```

Как поставить список в строку?
Как поставить отступ кнопке 640px

Comment: `li { display: inline-block; } button { margin-left: 640px;}`. Вы свою проблему гуглили хотябы? Тут ведь ничего фантастически-необычного нет, даже проблемы нет. И у вас селекторы неправильные: `ul.header_menu {
 
}

ul.header_menu li {
 

}`

Comment: @Klimenkomud сомневаюсь, что гуглит, у него  11 вопросов и ни одно принятого ответа...  и спасибо не скажет...

Comment: А ты смотрел на результат кода?

Comment: @VitalikSlobodyanuyk А ты собственно к кому обращаешься? По результатам кода твоя кнопка имеет отступ.